# Mailer error: Could not instantiate mail function for php mailer function

Tags: php, email

I want to sent mail by using xampp.So I used phpmailer function.But I got these error "Mailer error: Could not instantiate mail function".
My php code is following

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->Host     = "localhost"; // SMTP server

$mail->Port = 25;

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->Username = "myothantspo@gmail.com";

$mail->Password = "password";

$mail->From     = "myothantspo@gmail.com";

$mail->AddAddress("webdev3@myanmars.net");

$mail->Subject  = "no subject";

$mail->Body     = "this is a test message";

if(!$mail->Send()) {

  echo 'Message was not sent.';

  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;

} else {

  echo 'Message has been sent.';

}
```

My setting for php.ini is following

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
sendmail_from = myothantspo@gmail.com
```

Comment: As I'm not familiar with the workings of Windows, my only thought on the subject would be, have you actually installed an SMTP server on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Most of your configuration (`Host`, `Port`, `SMTPAuth` etc) relates to PHPMailer's own SMTP handler rather than PHP's built-in `mail` function.

If, as it therefore appears, you want PHPMailer to send email using SMTP instead of `mail` then you need to add `$mail->IsSMTP();` to your code somewhere before you call `$mail->Send()`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include phpmailer? Like this:

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
```

Or you might want to check this:

> https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer